# Invalid argument `data[7].refer` passed into DataTable with ID 'table'. Expected one of type [string, number, boolean]

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

Getting error message when passed the `def info2(row)` into the callback. Anyone can assist?

> > Invalid argument `data[7].refer` passed into DataTable with ID "table".
> > Expected one of type [string, number, boolean].

Code:

```
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.offline import plot

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Output,Input, State
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import dash_table
from dash_table import DataTable, FormatTemplate
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web


from datetime import date, datetime


import pyodbc
import os
import psycopg2

from plotly.io import write_image
import flask
import base64
```

```
@app.callback(
    Output('table', 'data'), 
    Input('id', 'value')
    )


def update_table(selection):
    if len (selection) == 0:
        return dash.no_update
    
    else:  
        dff = df[df['ID'] == selection]  

        
        transpose = dff.melt(id_vars = ['Reference_ID','Customer ID','Amount']
                  ,var_name = ['header']
                  ,value_name = 'info')
        
        
        info = transpose[~transpose['header'].isin(['Product', 'Customer ID'
                    , 'Name', 'Amount'])].fillna('No')
       
        new_info = info.copy()
        
        def info2(row):
            if row['header'] == 'Settled Date':
                return info['Customer ID'].unique()
            
            elif row['header'] == 'Rejected Date':
                return 'go to the next page'
            
            return ''


        # new_info['refer'] = new_info.apply (lambda row: info2(row), axis=1)
        new_info['refer'] = new_info.apply (info2, axis=1)
        
        
     
        columns = new_info[['header','info', 'refer']]


        data= columns.to_dict('records')

       
        return data
```

Comment: what framework are you using that you're getting the `app.callback` decorator from?

Comment: dash components

Comment: fyi, in your apply call, there's no need to use a lambda since you already defined the info2 function.  the way you're using lambda just aliases the call to info2.  you could instead do `new_info.apply(info2, axis=1)`

Comment: amend to `new_info.apply (info2, axis=1)` but the error still occur. Any idea on this?

Comment: it might be helpful to see what data is in `new_info` when you get errors.  right now anyone reading your question is just guessing at what the contents of your dataframes are.  giving some example dataframes that you know produce the error might also help you narrow down the cause of the problem.  I think you can probably strip away everything outside of your `update_table` function to work from a more focused point.  Maybe even throw that isolated code into a jupyter notebook to play around with it?